# jQuery before() method is breaking a generated sub menu when using jQuery 1.9.1, fine on previous version,

Tags: jquery

I am building a select drop down menu for mobile devices based on a pre-existing UL, this was working fine with an old version of jQuery (1.4.1). However, I have updated jQuery to version 1.9.1 and the code now breaks the menu. The section which is breaking is actually the child menu of the section that you are currently viewing.

```
var mobileMenu = function (menuParent, prevSibling) {

    var $select = $('<select>', {
        class: 'mobileMenu'
    }).insertAfter(prevSibling);

    $(menuParent).each(function () {
        var $li = $(this),
            $a = $li.find('> a'),
            $p = $li.parents('li'),
            prefix = new Array($p.length + 1).join('-');

        var $option = $('<option>')
            .text(prefix + ' ' + $a.text())
            .val($a.attr('href'))

        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            $option.attr('selected', true);
        }

        $option.appendTo($select);

        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            mobileSubNav($select);
        }

    });

    $(".mobileMenu").change(function () {
        window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });
};

var mobileSubNav = function (navContainerName) {
    $('.main_nav_sub li').each(function () {
        var $li = $(this),
        $a = $li.find('> a'),
        $p = $li.parents('li'),
        prefix = new Array($p.length + 1).join('-');

        var $option = $('<option>')
        .text(prefix + '--' + $a.text())
        .val($a.attr('href'));
        $option.before(navContainerName);
    });
}
```

It appears to be the 3rd to last line - the before() method. I see on the upgrade guide for jQuery version 1.9 it states 'attempting to use .after(), .before(), or .replaceWith() on a node without a parent has no effect'. Does this mean my script is breaking becuase the parent element is not yet added to the dom? Could anyone shed any light on what is happening and point me in the firrection to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of things need to be changed here compared to 1.4.1. Be sure to use jQuery Migrate, it will help find many of them.

`class: 'mobileMenu'`

That's always been an error on some browsers regardless of jQuery, you need to quote the word `class` since it's a keyword:

`'class': 'mobileMenu'`

The use of `.attr()` for setting properties has been deprecated since 1.6, so this should be `.prop()` instead:

`$option.attr('selected', true);`

On your question about `.before()` I am not sure why it worked in the first place. Seems like `navContainerName` is the select element and if it is you should be using `.appendTo()` or `.prependTo()` to add options.

Comment: Thanks, I used the appendTo() method instead and that works fine. I also updated the class. Thanks also for pointing me towards jQuery Migrate. Something I hadn't heard of and will use in the future.